# Textbox validation in wpf using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried the code in the below link.But my form with 3 textboxes is not getting highlighted upon button click.Do i need to change anything in the code?

https://www.eidias.com/blog/2012/7/9/simple-validation-in-wpf-mvvm-part-2

```
public class ProductModel : NotifyPropertyChangeBase
   2: {
   3:      private String name;
   4:      public String Name
   5:      {
   6:          get
   7:          {
   8:              return name;
   9:          }
  10:          set
  11:          {
  12:              name = value;
  13:              NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Name);
  14:          }
  15:      }
  16:  
  17:      private decimal price;
  18:      public decimal Price
  19:      {
  20:          get
  21:          {
  22:              return price;
  23:          }
  24:          set
  25:          {
  26:              price = value;
  27:              NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Price);
  28:          }
  29:      }
  30:  
  31:      private int amount;
  32:      public int Amount
  33:      {
  34:          get
  35:          {
  36:              return amount;
  37:          }
  38:          set
  39:          {
  40:              amount = value;
  41:              NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Amount);
  42:          }
  43:      }     
  44: }
```

UserControl x:Class="WPFValidationApplication.Views.ProductForm"
   2:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   3:              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   4:              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   5:              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   6:              xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFValidationApplication.Utils"
   7:              d:DesignHeight="300"
   8:              d:DesignWidth="448"
   9:              mc:Ignorable="d">
  10:  
  11:     <Grid>
  12:         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  13:             <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  14:             <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  15:             <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  16:             <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  17:             <RowDefinition Height="259*" />
  18:         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  19:         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  20:             <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
  21:             <ColumnDefinition Width="308*" />
  22:         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  23:         <Label Grid.Row="0"
  24:                Height="28"
  25:                Margin="0,0,10,0"
  26:                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  27:                VerticalAlignment="Center"
  28:                Content="Name:" />
  29:         <Label Grid.Row="1"
  30:                Height="28"
  31:                Margin="0,0,10,0"
  32:                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  33:                VerticalAlignment="Center"
  34:                Content="Price:" />
  35:         <Label Grid.Row="2"
  36:                Height="28"
  37:                Margin="0,0,10,0"
  38:                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  39:                VerticalAlignment="Center"
  40:                Content="Amount:" />
  41:  
  42:  
  43:         <TextBox Name="txtName"
  44:                  Grid.Row="0"
  45:                  Grid.Column="1"
  46:                  Width="200"
  47:                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  48:                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  49:                  Text="{Binding Model.Name,
  50:                                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
  51:  
  52:         <TextBox Name="txtPrice"
  53:                  Grid.Row="1"
  54:                  Grid.Column="1"
  55:                  Width="200"
  56:                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  57:                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  58:                  Text="{Binding Model.Price,
  59:                                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
  60:  
  61:         <TextBox Name="txtAmount"
  62:                  Grid.Row="2"
  63:                  Grid.Column="1"
  64:                  Width="200"
  65:                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  66:                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  67:                  Text="{Binding Model.Amount,
  68:                                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
  69:  
  70:         <Button Grid.Row="3"
  71:                 Grid.Column="1"
  72:                 Width="75"
  73:                 Height="23"
  74:                 Margin="0,0,20,0"
  75:                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
  76:                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
  77:                 Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
  78:                 Content="Save">
  79:         </Button>
  80:     </Grid>
  81: </UserControl>

public class ProductModel : NotifyPropertyChangeBase , IDataErrorInfo
   2: {
   3:     [Properties...]
   4:  
   5:     public string Error
   6:     {
   7:         get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
   8:     }
   9:  
  10:     public string this[string columnName]
  11:     {
  12:         get
  13:         {
  14:             string result = string.Empty;
  15:             switch (columnName)
  16:             {
  17:                 case "Name": if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) result = "Name is required!"; break;
  18:                 case "Price": if ((Price < 10) || (Price > 1000)) result = "Price must be between 10 and 1000"; break;
  19:                 case "Amount": if ((Amount < 1) || (Amount > 100)) result = "Amount must be between 1 and 100"; break;
  20:             };
  21:             return result;
  22:         }
  23:     }
  24:  
  25: }

public class ProductFormViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangeBase
   2: {
   3:     public ProductModel Model { get; set; }
   4:  
   5:     public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
   6:  
   7:     public ProductFormViewModel()
   8:     {
   9:         Model = new ProductModel();
  10:         SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveExecute);
  11:     }
  12:  
  13:     private void SaveExecute()
  14:     {
  15:        //dummy
  16:     }    
  17: }


   1: <Style TargetType="TextBox">
   2:             <Style.Triggers>
   3:                 <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
   4:                     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
   5:                 </Trigger>
   6:             </Style.Triggers>
   7:         </Style>
```

This displays a form with 3 textboxes and a button .Now i changed the code to suffice my requirement.

```
public class ProductModel : NotifyPropertyChangeBase , IDataErrorInfo
2: {
3: public bool IsValidating = false;
4:  
5: public Dictionary<string, string> Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
6:  
7: ...properties...
8:  
9: public bool IsValid()
10: {
11: IsValidating = true;
12: try
13: {
14: NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Name);
15: NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Price);
16: NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Amount);
17: }
18: finally
19: {
20: IsValidating = false;
21: }
22: return (Errors.Count() == 0);
23: }
24:  
25: public string Error
26: {
27: get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
28: }
29:  
30: public string this[string columnName]
31: {
32: get
33: {
34: string result = string.Empty;
35: if (!IsValidating) return result;
36: Errors.Remove(columnName);
37: switch (columnName)
38: {
39: case "Name": if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) result = "Name is required!"; break;
40: case "Price": if ((Price < 10) || (Price > 1000)) result = "Price must be between 10 and 1000"; break;
41: case "Amount": if ((Amount < 1) || (Amount > 100)) result = "Amount must be between 1 and 100"; break;
42: };
43: if (result != string.Empty) Errors.Add(columnName, result);
44: return result;
45: }
46: }
47:  
48: public ProductModel()
49: {
50: }
51: }

private void SaveExecute()
2: {
3: Model.IsValid();
4: }
```

Comment: Where is your code, so we can help? Also, I'm not clicking that link...

Answer (score 0):

This is simple true way for make yourself validation rules for binding:

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int MinimalLength { get; set; }
    public int MaximalLength { get; set; }
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if(value is string validatedString)
        {
            if (validatedString.Length < MinimalLength)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Text must be larger.");
            if (validatedString.Length > MaximalLength)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Text must be shorter.");
        }
        return new ValidationResult(true, "");
    }
}
```

**xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp15"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:MyValidationRule MinimalLength="2" MaximalLength="10"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The binded property must have an implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.